# Can't run expo project on LAN without internet connectivity

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using OSX and when I tried to run my expo app on connected android or iphones, I got an error saying

> Something went wrong.
>
> Could not load exp://102.168.43.87:19000. Network response timed out.

But when I'm using a Windows system to start expo, its working on the same LAN without internet.

Any solution?